# Cannot change status bar style

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I'd like to use the `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` API on each of my view controllers (and I have lots of them) but even though I do implement it, the method is never called.
I tried calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` or `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` but it didn't help.

I tried this on the latest iOS 7 beta 6.

Possible important note - I provide an SDK for apps to use.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Just a reminder, that iOS7 SDK is still under NDA. However you can find an answer in the Apple Developer Forums. Good luck!

Comment: @NikolaKirev thanks for the reminder and the tip. Now that I have my solution, would you say it will be wise to publish it here now ?

Comment: The best thing you can do is to delete the question, but if you do not want to do that, just wait a few days until the NDA is lifted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your top level view controller will normally have control of the status bar.  If you your want child view controllers to have control, you will need to call

`(UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle`

to change where `-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` is going to be called. Or, you could implement callbacks to custom methods in the top level controller to change the style and call `- (void)setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` as necessary.